# Android: how to play audio file?

Tags: java, android

I've create a custom ListView with title and artist TextView, and with play and stop Button. The problem is that when I press play or stop Button, audio file doesn't start. How is it possible?
I've uploaded my custom Adapter and my AudioToSendActivity class:

AudioAdapter.java

```
public class AudioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> audioList;

    public AudioAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
        super(context, 0 , list);
        mContext = context;
        audioList = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItem = convertView;
        if (listItem == null)
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.audio_row, parent, false);

        String audio = audioList.get(position);
        String[] items = audio.split("\n");
        String title = "", artist = "";
        if (items.length > 1) {
            title = items[0];
        }

        if (items.length > 2) {
            artist = items[1];
        }

        ImageView imageAudio = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.audio_image);

        TextView titleView = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.audio_title);
        titleView.setText(title);

        TextView artistView = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.audio_artist);
        artistView.setText(artist);

        return listItem;
    }
}
```

AudioToSendActivity.java

```
public class AudioToSendActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1;
    private Button sendButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_to_send);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.audio_list_view);
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.send_audio);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AudioToSendActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(AudioToSendActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AudioToSendActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
            }
            else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AudioToSendActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
            }
        }
        else {
            upload();
        }

    }

    private void upload() {
        listView = findViewById(R.id.audio_list_view);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        getAudio();
        adapter = new AudioAdapter(this, arrayList);  //AudioAdapter<String>(this, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // open music player to play desired song
            }
        });
    }

    public void getAudio() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri audioUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor audioCursor = contentResolver.query(audioUri, null, null, null, null);

        if(audioCursor != null && audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int audioTitle = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int audioArtist = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

            do {
                String currentTitle = audioCursor.getString(audioTitle);
                String currentDate = audioCursor.getString(audioArtist);

                arrayList.add(currentTitle + "\n" + currentDate);
            }
            while (audioCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST: {
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AudioToSendActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        upload();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: As i can see the mediaplayer is only initiazed, so nothing to play? aAybe this helps: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer#java

Comment: Yes, it doesn' t give the possibility to select the audio file, why?

Answer (score 0):

try this. Get the uri of your file and set it like this:

```
//for example

public void getAudio() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri audioUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor audioCursor = contentResolver.query(audioUri, null, null, null, null);

        if(audioCursor != null && audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int audioTitle = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int audioArtist = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            //get the song path here and ...
            int audiodata = audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

            do {
                String currentTitle = audioCursor.getString(audioTitle);
                String currentDate = audioCursor.getString(audioArtist);
                //And here
                String currentPath = audioCursor.getString(audioPath);

                //And add it to your list however you like
                arrayList.add(currentTitle + "\n" + currentDate + "\n" + currentPath);
            }
            while (audioCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

And then retrieve the path and make a uri from it and the rest:

```
Uri myAudioUri = Uri.parse("file:///" + currentPath);

//or

Uri myAudioUri = Uri.parse(currentPath);
//didn't have time to check the lines above

MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(this, myAudioUri);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Comment: I'm taking audio file from device storage

Comment: just changed my answer. give it a try.

Comment: Yes I tried with this, but it doesn't show the files on the device.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't show the file on the device"? you are supposed to get the file path, convert it to a uri and then use it this way.

Comment: I've edited my question adding my classes, can you tell me where I have to add that code?

Comment: Try the new answer. sorry didn't have much time to spend on it.